# How to create a dotted shadowy effect on an image with CSS?

Tags: php, html, css

I would like to create the effect that can be seen on the website http://www.murmure.me/ when you hover on their images.

I know They use two different images but I would like to be able to this effect without 2 images, just with ONE picture (the one without the dots) and by using CSS. Is it possible ?

Comment: I dunno anything about dots, but combination [this article](http://www.gravitywell.co.uk/blog/post/how-to-make-a-image-greyscale-in-css) with a `transition` could be helpful.

Comment: @HashemQolami do you think css greyscale+svg described in the article work on mobile device's browsers (important for me) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mikel, you can't achieve a silk-screen effect using CSS and a single image.
It's not going to happen any time soon, in any cross-browser compatible way.

Maybe, eventually, when you can custom-program CSS filters using HLSL or similar...
But for the time-being, even with near-ish-future CSS-filters, I don't think that they're going to offer silk-screen, and THEN, you'd need to worry about that, along with the transition effects, and THEN you'd need to worry about browser support, with 2-image fallbacks for other browsers...

ie: you'd have to create the 2nd image and write the 2-image fallback which you were hoping there was a CSS filter for, to avoid making the 2nd image, in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty close: http://jsfiddle.net/LfXN3/8/

But, it requires a second element (not image, just element). The pseudo-element approach wasn't working because the opacity of it couldn't be animated.

```
<div>
    <div id="overlay"></div>
</div>​
```

CSS

```
div{
    background:url(http://placekitten.com/600/600) center center;
    width:400px;
    height:400px;

    -webkit-transition:all 2s;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
}

div:hover{
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
}

div #overlay{
    opacity:.5;
    display:block;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #777 25%, transparent 25%, transparent), -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, #777 25%, transparent 25%, transparent), -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 75%, #777 75%), -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, #000 75%, #777 75%);

    background-size:2px 2px;
    width:400px;
    height:400px;

    -webkit-transition:opcaity 2s;
}

div:hover #overlay{
    opacity:0;   
}
```

I've managed to get that tiny bit closer by incorporating Dudley Storey's technique into mine: http://jsfiddle.net/LfXN3/14/

The main difference being this:

```
div #overlay{
    opacity:1;
    display:block;
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0) 45%, rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 46%),
-webkit-radial-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0) 45%, rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 46%),
    url(http://placekitten.com/600/600);
    background-position: 0 0, 2px 2px, center center;
    background-size:4px 4px, 4px 4px, 600px 600px;
    width:400px;
    height:400px;

    -webkit-transition:opacity 2s;
}
```

Comment: May I suggest removing the "close but not quite there" section from your answer? Your second attempt is perfect, but most people probably won't make it to that demo link.

Comment: @ThinkingStiff it's not "perfect", because if you pay attention to the images on the actual site which is referenced in the main question, they aren't just desaturated -- they are silk-screened: the black and white images are made up of little dots, the size and spacing of which are chosen to control the visual contrast of that area.  In CSS, you can desaturate, but there is currently no cross-browser way of controlling the visual contrast by breaking the shadows and highlights into circles. That's why a desaturation-only technique is "close", not "perfect".

Comment: @Norguard absolutely correct. Blend-modes are in the works, but aren't yet available. Also, I think ThinkingStiff was suggesting that I remove the code for the first attempt, which I've done.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, can be done with a single image, using plain CSS3 and a filter: [demo, and a brief explanation, on my blog](http://demosthenes.info/blog/613/Create-a-Silkscreen-Effect-For-Web-Images-With-CSS3). Right now the greyscale-to-color transition seems especially slow in Firefox (as it has to use the SVG equivalent to the filter), so I've removed it from the demo for the time being.

```
div#silkscreen {
background:
-webkit-radial-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0) 45%, rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 46%),
-webkit-radial-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0) 45%, rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 46%), 
url(lotus.jpg);
background: -moz-radial-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0) 45%, rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 46%),
-moz-radial-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0) 45%, rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 46%), 
url(lotus.jpg);
background-position: 0 0, 2px 2px;
background-size:4px 4px, 4px 4px, cover;
-webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
filter: url(desaturate.svg#greyscale);
filter: grayscale(1);
transition: 1.3s;
}
div#silkscreen:hover { -webkit-filter: grayscale(0); filter: none; }
div#silkscreen img { max-width: 100%; opacity: 0; }}
div#silkscreen:hover { -webkit-filter: grayscale(0); }
div#silkscreen img { max-width: 100%; opacity: 0; }

<div id=silkscreen>
<img src=lotus.jpg alt="">
</div>
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: The "cross-hatching" also needs to fade out.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst it is possible to convert a colour image to greyscale using the css3 greyscale filter, it currently only works in Chrome.

```
-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
```

A workaround to get that effect without the use of jQuery is to use two images and css3 transitions.

```
-webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
-moz-transition:    opacity 0.5s;
-o-transition:      opacity 0.5s;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using the original picture (without the dots) and another image just made of a single small dot (something like http://www.scottecatalog.com/images.nsf/Images/dot/$FILE/Dot.gif) and with a repeat attribute, repeat the dot all over the original image with the right space between the dots and with z-index property (so that the dots are placed in font of the original image)?

We are still using 2 pictures but at least it would be easy to replicate this effect for any image, whatever original image you have under it.
Would that make sense?