# How to achieve a silk-screen effect (a dotted shadowy effect) on an image with javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I would like to create the effect that can be seen on the website http://www.murmure.me/ when you hover on their images.

I know they use two different images but I would like to be able to **replicate this kind of visual effect without 2 images**, just **by using ONE picture** (the one without the dots) **and by using using javascript/jquery**. Is it possible ?

This question follows the original one which tried to solve the issue with CSS, but it seemed impossible, or only on too few browsers : [How to create a dotted shadowy effect on an image with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13256143/how-to-create-a-dotted-shadowy-effect-on-an-image-with-css/13256741#13256741))

Thank you for your help!

Comment: How is this different from your last question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13256143/how-to-create-a-dotted-shadowy-effect-on-an-image-with-css?

Comment: i try to use something else than pure css

Comment: @Madbreaks would you know of a demo or a github-like source code that does this effect ?

Comment: I am usually all for pure CSS or alternative solutions for avoiding lots of images, but I think Occam's razor may cut the other way on this one, friend.

Comment: @MaxPRafferty i would have liked to go with pure css indeed but i think i don't have the choice:(

Comment: Downvoted because you keep asking the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13256143/how-to-create-a-dotted-shadowy-effect-on-an-image-with-css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll suggest you to search for canvas element in html5, supported in all modern browsers.

As canvas is subject to cross domain policy for media (even image), i cannot set you a jsfiddle sample.
So i set you a sample here to give you the idea: [HERE](http://bonex.fr/testforstackoverflow/)

Here is the source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>HTML5 Canvas</title>

<style type="text/css">
img{position:absolute;}
canvas{display:none;position:absolute;z-index:100;}
</style>

</head>

<body>
 <img src="beach_volley_layout.jpg"></img>   
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var canvas;
$('img').mouseover(function(){

    canvas = createCanvasOverlay(this);
    $(canvas).fadeIn(600);
}).mouseout(function(){
    $(canvas).fadeOut(600);
});

function createCanvasOverlay(image) {

    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
        canvasContext = canvas.getContext("2d");

    // Make it the same size as the image
    canvas.width = image.width;
    canvas.height = image.height;

    // Drawing the default version of the image on the canvas:
    canvasContext.drawImage(image, 0, 0);


    // Taking the image data and storing it in the imageData array:
    var imageData = canvasContext.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height),
        data = imageData.data;

    // Loop through all the pixels in the imageData array, and modify
    // the red, green, and blue color values.
    for (var i = 0, z = data.length; i < z; i++) {

        // The values for red, green and blue are consecutive elements
        // in the imageData array. We modify the three of them at once:
        data[i] = ((data[i] < 128) ? (2 * data[i] * data[i] / 255) : 20);
        data[++i] = ((data[i] < 128) ? (2 * data[i] * data[i] / 255) : (255 - 2 * (255 - data[i]) * (255 - data[i]) / 255));
        data[++i] = ((data[i] < 128) ? (2 * data[i] * data[i] / 255) : 20);

        // After the RGB elements is the alpha value, but we leave it the same.
        ++i;
    }

    // Putting the modified imageData back to the canvas.
    canvasContext.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);

    // Inserting the canvas in the DOM, before the image:
    image.parentNode.insertBefore(canvas, image);

    return canvas;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it will be a two part issue: 1) Desaturation/Greying out the image. 2) applying many little dots all over it, in an ordered fashion.

1) This is fairly straightforward. Position another element with an semi-transparent grey background over your image. On mouseover, fade the element to full transparency.

2) Assuming cross-browser compatibility is still a concern, there is only one way i can see to accomplish this without a canvas. Youll need to create a circular element (using border-radius) of the correct size, then clone it over and over across the width and height of your image. You will need to calculate the area in your "pixels" of the image, then drop that many in. I would try just left floating them in the transparency container, rather than absolutely positioning them in a loop.

From http://www.tutorialsbucket.com/draw-basic-shapes-css3-tips-and-tricks, here is the css for a single dot:

```
.circle {
    height: 2px;
    width: 2px;
    background-color: #72b8c2;
    border: 2px solid #234e5e;

    /* In this case we use half of the
     width and height as radius. */

    border-radius: 100px;
    -moz-border-radius: 100px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
}
```

I set the circle width to 2px, to give it a slightly more "print" like effect.
Clone an element with that class and a left float as a child of your image overlay, as many times as width * height / circle-diameter works out to, along the lines of:

```
for(var i=0; i<=$('#container').width()*$('#container').height()/$('#originCircle').width(); i++)
{
$(container).append($('#originElement').clone())
}
```

May god have mercy on your DOM.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using CSS3 filters for desaturating:

```
.desaturate { filter: grayscale(100%);
-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
-moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
-ms-filter: grayscale(100%);
-o-filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

Then apply another div layered on top of the image with the background repeating as the little circles. You can use JS to size this div properly.

Comment: I you want to stick with CSS, this seems like a good option. Maybe overlay an SVG on the image for the dots?